# Android Tabhost, switching orientation reload is slow

Tags: android, keyboard, landscape, android-tabhost, tabview

I have an app that is in portrait mode, but some screens should have a landscape mode for phones with physical keyboards.

I am using tabhost and I noticed that when I allow a forced orientation change, it reloads EVERY tab and is kind of slow.

Is there a way to allow a forced orientation change (such as only when the hard keyboard is popped out) AND only reload that view to be in landscape mode? I want to do this without the lag of reloading all of the activities. My tabhost currently will cycle through every activity on an orientation change. I know this has something to do with redrawing the "alive" activities on orientation change but the tabhost just magnifies that redrawing.

The activities that require an optional landscape mode also need to be run within the tabview.

Insight appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You prevent the Activity from being destroyed by handling the orientation change yourself.

Edit the activities your Manifest:

```
<activity  android:name=".MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

And then override in your Activities:

```
       @Override 
       public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) { 
         //ignore orientation change 
         super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); 
       }
```

BUT you have to know that restarting is used to load special resources for each orientation you might have strange effect if you don't actually do handle the change. There are reasons for the reload.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Why do you have a dot in front of MyActivity, why do I want to ignore the orientation change with `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);`? As is, this doesn't seem to be working for me now. I would like only particular activities in the tab group to be able to reload without reloading the entire tab